# how do I get screen to show comamnds given?

Tags: command-line, bash, screen, serial-port

I have a serial device that I am trying to figure out the commands for. I know the baudrate, and seem to be able to connect. Using $`screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600,cs8`

the problem I have is that every command returns `Error:005 Illegal command`

is there a way for me to set screen to show the commands I have given thus far?

[image]

Comment: According to manual: https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen the parameter to `screen` command is a _command_ that you want to run inside `screen` session. Are you sure `screen` is actually the command you wanted to run? What did you exactly want to do?

Comment: @raj, I think the OP is using `screen` as a VT100 emulator to connect to another machine using a serial port. I've did the same thing years ago. It means you can use your laptop instead of lugging around a spare monitor and keyboard.

Comment: To me, it looks like the "Error:005" is the response from the other machine. It's not a `screen` error. I've never seen `screen` save a history -- it's just not that smart. As a VT100 emulator, it's real *dumb* terminal. Glad you managed to connect at all; the baud rate catches a lot of folks. Are you sure that the port you are connected to permits login? Back in the day, I needed to activate serial ports before access: `# getty -L ttyS0 9600 vt100` on the machine before I could attach the serial cable. Without that, it would ignore all input.

Comment: @user535733 But IMHO you cannot use `screen` like in that example. `screen` needs a **command** as a parameter and `/dev/ttyUSB0` is not a command. An actual command that connects to the serial port is missing here. As for "saving history", I don't know what do you exactly mean, but `screen` can save the entire session to a logfile (Ctrl-A H) and also has a scrollback buffer that you can review (Ctrl-A Esc).

Comment: @raj seems like we both have half an answer, but neither of us seem to have a satisfying answer.

Comment: You might need to type control-j instead of return to end a line. There are other emulators you might be able to try, eg `picocom` has a `-echo` option to locally echo what you type. Otherwise, once screen is running, you might be able to use `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 echo` from a 2nd command line.